# I have a memory leak of an array from a custom class, how can I clear / "dispose" it?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ants

I have an object being held in memory.  The object is "Trigram()"

This is a small number of the strings;

```
tmodels("en") = New String() {" th", "the"}
```

is then used like this

```
For Each key As String In tmodels.Keys
        Dim t As String() = DirectCast(tmodels(key), String())
        Models(key) = New TrigramModel(t)
    Next
    'release temp data structure
    tmodels = Nothing
```

At the risk of posting too much the whole TrigramModel class is below.

```
 Public Class TrigramModel

    Private m_trigrams As Trigram()
    Public ReadOnly Property Trigrams() As Trigram()
        Get
            Return m_trigrams
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal trigramsAndCounts As Hashtable)
        Dim keys2 As New List(Of String)()
        Dim scores2 As New List(Of Integer)()
        'convert hashtable to arrays
        For Each key As String In trigramsAndCounts.Keys
            keys2.Add(key)
            scores2.Add(CInt(trigramsAndCounts(key)))
        Next

        Dim keys As String() = keys2.ToArray()
        Dim scores As Integer() = scores2.ToArray()

        ' sort array results
        Array.Sort(scores, keys)
        Array.Reverse(keys)
        Array.Reverse(scores)

        'build final array
        Dim result As New List(Of Trigram)()
        For x As Integer = 0 To keys.Length - 1
            result.Add(New Trigram(keys(x), scores(x)))
        Next


        m_trigrams = result.ToArray()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal tgrams As String())
        Dim keys2 As New List(Of String)()
        Dim scores2 As New List(Of Integer)()
        'convert hashtable to arrays
        Dim score As Integer = 0
        For Each key As String In tgrams
            keys2.Add(key)
            scores2.Add(System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(score), score - 1))
        Next

        Dim keys As String() = keys2.ToArray()
        Dim scores As Integer() = scores2.ToArray()

        ' sort array results
        Array.Sort(scores, keys)
        Array.Reverse(keys)
        Array.Reverse(scores)

        'build final array
        Dim result As New List(Of Trigram)()
        For x As Integer = 0 To keys.Length - 1
            result.Add(New Trigram(keys(x), scores(x)))
        Next


        m_trigrams = result.ToArray()
    End Sub

    Public Function HasTrigram(ByVal trigram As String) As Boolean
        For Each t As Trigram In m_trigrams
            If t.t = trigram Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Function GetScore(ByVal trigram As String) As Integer
        For Each t As Trigram In m_trigrams
            If t.t = trigram Then
                Return t.score
            End If
        Next
        Throw New Exception((Convert.ToString("No score found for '") & trigram) + "'")
    End Function


End Class

Public Class Trigram

    Public t As String = Nothing
    Public score As Integer = 0
    Public Sub New(ByVal t As String, ByVal s As Integer)
        Me.t = t
        score = s
    End Sub

End Class
```

How can I deal with Trigramm() or any other issues you see in this class?

Comment: What makes you think there is an issue? Everything you have is managed for you and does not require Disposal

Comment: How does `Convert.ToString("No score found for '") ` need to be converted to string?

Comment: @OneFineDay not sure, this is not my code.

Comment: @Alex I am profiling this with ANTS memory profiler and it is telling me it is still hanging around.

Comment: @darbid So what?  The GC will collect it when it needs to (when there's memory pressure).  There's nothing unmanaged so there's nothing to "dispose" of.

Comment: Thanks D Stanley. I have read a little but about GC, but I thought the point of a memory profiler is that it forces a Collect before it takes a snapshot.  Of course it cannot force .NET to do a full collect.  So Multiple snapshots force multiple collects and I would have assumed one of them would mean the GC cleaned up this object. But it stays there. Any way I can test your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended you do this. But you can force garbage collection to see what is happening, or test your theory.

```
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()
```

There is the rare case where it might be a good idea to use it, as I have found.